# Is the term/word "stamp" the same as "seal" when talking about invoices

Tags: synonyms, translation

I'm doing a translation about an invoice process from spanish to english and not quite sure how to translate "timbre" (in spanish) to english not sure if would it stamp/stamp number/seal

Any help would it be appreciated.

Comment: We need more information here. Invoices tend to be subject to quite different legal processes in different countries: stamping, sealing , attaching an apostille are all possible. In the UK invoices are not very significant legally, but each trader can have individual requirements to formalise whether they are to be paid, have already been paid, or should not be paid at all.

Comment: I dont' have much information, it's a LATAM document, almost sure it's from  Mexico, I know "timbre" is used in Mexican invoices, and its some sort of validation of the invoice, check #7 here: https://sovos.com/blog/mexico-cfdi-and-contabilidad-electronica-eaccounting-the-basics-explained/  it gets translated as "government seal" ...so probably that would be the term I'm looking for, but still curious if it's the same as stamp number/stamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, the reference is to a specific legal process that just does not apply in other countries or apply in the same way. I also notice that the website you referred to does not even try to translate timbre fiscal despite otherwise being in very good English.

Depending on how many times the words occur in the document you are translating, you have two main options: if they occur many times don't translate the term at all but just explain it once at the first occurrence  - 'timbre fiscal' (official stamp of the tax authorities); alternatively if the words occur just once or twice translate as 'official stamp'.